# binding props to parent state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

A react component which gets 2 property of parent state as props to make svg of graph,

```
        const lines =
        Object.keys(this.props.nodes).length !== 0 &&
        this.props.input.map(line =>
            <line
                id={`${line[0]}${line[1]}`}
                x1={this.props.nodes[line[0]]["x"]}
                x2={this.props.nodes[line[1]]["x"]}
                y1={this.props.nodes[line[0]]["y"]}
                y2={this.props.nodes[line[1]]["y"]}
            />
        );
```

the problem is since input is initially empty object i get error while populating **lines** , i tried to fix it by adding first line but still i get below error every time input is changed
" TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined "

parent state :

```
state = {
    input: [],   // sample : [[A,B]]
    nodes: {},   // sample : {A : {x:100, y: 150}, B : {x:200, y: 350}}
};
```

parent graph creator function (triggered by a button ):

```
    createGraph = () => {
    let newNodes = {};
    this.state.input.forEach(line => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            let value = line[i];
            if (
                // !(value in this.state.nodes) &&
                value !== undefined &&
                value !== ""
            ) {
                newNodes[value] = this.randomPosition();
            }
        }
    });
    this.setState({nodes: newNodes});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think you have to check and wait for the props to be defined. Something like this.

```
    const lines =
    Object.keys(this.props.nodes).length !== 0 && this.props.nodes[line[0]] && this.props.nodes[line[1]] &&
    this.props.input.map(line =>
        <line
            id={`${line[0]}${line[1]}`}
            x1={this.props.nodes[line[0]]["x"]}
            x2={this.props.nodes[line[1]]["x"]}
            y1={this.props.nodes[line[0]]["y"]}
            y2={this.props.nodes[line[1]]["y"]}
        />
    );
```